# wp_nonce vs jwt

Tags: rest-api, security, authentication, nonce

I’ve recently added jwt authentication to my website because frontend of my site is completely decoupled from backend.
What I haven’t thought of is that I could use wp_nonce instead of jwt - create nonce on backend, store it on frontend and send it with every request till it expires.

What drawbacks does wp nonce method have vs jwt method?

Also, nonces are used to secure wordpress from csrf for example.
Is there any way to secure rest api from csrf, other than setting cors rules correctly (to allow only frontend domain?

Comment: nonces are not authentication tokens, if your site is only accepting API requests from users on that site then I do not see any advantages to using JWT to authenticate REST API requests. The standard cookie + nonce that comes with WordPress would be enough assuming HTTPS is set up

Comment: Currently I've got frontend on another domain on another server (built with React- GatsbyJS). I think I could host frontend on subdomain (or backend on subdomain and frontend on main domain). Is standard wordpress session doable with this setup? I want smooth SPA experience on frontend, so I would need to send request to rest api anyway. I probably would need to create login endpoint where I manually log in user with username and password and create authentication cookie manually. I would need nonce that lasts as long as wordpress session too....

Comment: This depends on where the frontend and backend are located in relation to each other, but that's not a WP problem, that's a general browser cookie scope problem. I do not see a need for the two to have separate domains, it needlessly complicates things. Either use a WordPress theme that just bootstraps a SPA, or, route `wp-*` URLs to WordPress and everything else to Node or whatever is serving your SPA.

Comment: And as I said earlier, ***nonces are not authentication tokens***. An authentication protocol based entirely off of nonces would be disastrous, and a gross misunderstanding of what they're intended for.

Answer (score 0):

> What I haven’t thought of is that I could use wp_nonce instead of jwt - create nonce on backend, store it on frontend and send it with every request till it expires.

> What drawbacks does wp nonce method have vs jwt method?

**Using nonces as a replacement for an authentication protocol, or as a session identifier would be insecure.** ***A nonce is not an authentication or identifying token.***

Using it as an authentication token is not going to work, or rather it will function but it will have incredibly weak security.

The purpose of a nonce is to prove that when a user takes an action, that they intended to take that action, that the request was deliberate. It is not proof that the user are who they said they are, and it provides no guarantees in relation to identity.

If they are used in authentication it is as a test to detect replay attacks and avoid a recorded login request being resent by an attacker, but they can't be used to verify and login a user.

TLDR: This is a bad idea, nonces cannot be used as authenticators. *stick to a known good method that is well defined and battle hardened if you want security and safety*.

[And don't roll your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own)

---

Lets test just how secure a WP nonce would be, at the time of writing, this is the implementation WP uses:

```php
function wp_create_nonce( $action = -1 ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $uid  = (int) $user->ID;
    if ( ! $uid ) {
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/pluggable.php */
        $uid = apply_filters( 'nonce_user_logged_out', $uid, $action );
    }
 
    $token = wp_get_session_token();
    $i     = wp_nonce_tick();
 
    return substr( wp_hash( $i . '|' . $action . '|' . $uid . '|' . $token, 'nonce' ), -12, 10 );
}
```

In the proposed scheme, this would be simplified down to:

```php
function wp_create_nonce( $action = -1 ) {
    $i     = wp_nonce_tick();
    return substr( wp_hash( $i . '|' . $action . '||', 'nonce' ), -12, 10 );
}
```

So a user would need to know the action, the nonce tick, and the salt used by `wp_hash`. We will know the action, the nonce tick is a simple time calculation with some rounding, therefore we just need to bruteforce the salt.

We can do this by adjusting `wp_create_nonce` to use a version of `wp_hash` that cycles through every possible value for `wp_salt`. This will give us either the `AUTH_SALT` or `SECURE_AUTH_SALT` in `wp-config.php`.

From there on a chain of events occurs that allows us to impersonate anybody on your site. Mitigating this would involve the `nonce_user_logged_out` and devising a scheme to insert more user session based data, but this just delays the inevitable.

Comment: I think I formed my question in a bad way :( I dont want to use nonces as authenticators. I just need to store wp_nonce on frontend for users to be able to use protected routes of my rest api (which lets them modify their own data etc) for at least as long as their session is active. I just wanted to ask if storing wp_nonce on frontend for that long and continously using the same wp_nonce (which wordpress needs to authenticate user) with cookie to authenticate user is more vurnerable than just session cookie. If im hosting my SPA on nodejs I need to create that nonce on my wordpress install

Comment: In short - if I want to use wp_nonce + session instead of jwt in my SPA I need to create that nonce and make it valid for like 7 days on my wordpress install, then pass it to my frontend (lets say on subdomain) and pass both that same nonce and session id for 7 days. Isnt it vulnerable in some way?

Comment: OR I could refresh the nonce on every request. Again, just wanted to ask if it has some security implications

Comment: For the same reasons you shouldn't use nonces as session identifiers, nonces are meant to be throwaway values

Comment: So what should I do then? Wordpress REST API needs wp-nonce to authorize user (I need to pass both wp-nonce and session cookie to use api resources that need authorization). I'm using React static site generator (GatsbyJS) output (static html files with app on top of them) as frontend. I think I need to place it on subdomain atleast.

Comment: If you are using JWT for authentication then use JWT, there are JWT authentication plugins out there that handle REST authentication. Out of the box WP requires a nonce for authenticated API requests, but it isn't the nonce that's authenticating the user, it's the cookie, the nonce provides additional protection but it isn't a session identifier, and it provides no guarantees that the user is who they say they are.

Comment: Yes I'm using JWT auth plugin modified by me to suit my purposes. But these plugins are very simple, they don't provide blacklisting, refresh tokens etc logic so I need to code it by my self. Basically right now I'm creating my own authentication framework... So I started digging and thinking if what I'm doing is doable with wordpress session authentication via rest api.

Comment: And the only way to do it with session cookies and wordpress is to pass wp_nonce that will be valid as long as session cookie to frontend and save it there. Or to have my app bootstrapped inside wordpress environment and make new wp_nonce on every page load but I dont think I can host that simple gatsbyjs html files output in my wordpress install (or I'm wrong)

Comment: Also note that you don't have to use JWT/Cookies, OAuth1/2 is an option too, just be wary of creating your own authentication systems

Comment: Ok, thank you, I would've upvoted your answers but my reputation doesn't allow me to do that... Ill stick with JWT for now bcs I don't have that extended knowledge to use OAuth yet. I'm using google and facebook login on my website but in the end its all "transformed" into jwt.
Also I've created thread about blacklisting jwt in wordpress:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/382351/blacklisting-jwt-after-logout-in-wordpress
If you have time I would be grateful if you could take a look at my approach - if not, thank you anyway, few ideas appeared in my head after this conversation